# How to determine if user picked video or image?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

Using react native and expo, we want a user to be able to post a video or an image.

Here is the code:

```
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

const openImagePickerAsync = async() => {
    const permissionResult = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();

    if (permissionResult.granted === false) {
      setImage(null);
      setHasImage(false);
      alert('Permission to access camera roll is required!');
      return;
    }

    const pickerResult = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All, <---------------- allowing photos and video
      allowsEditing: true,
    });

    try {
      if (pickerResult.cancelled === true) {
        setHasImage(false);
        console.log('pickerResult is cancelled');
        return;
      }

      if (pickerResult !== null) {
        setHasImage(true);
        setImage(pickerResult.uri);
        console.log(image);
      } else {
        setImage(null);
        setHasImage(false);
        console.log('pickerResult is null');
        return;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

How do we make it so that we can know if a user picked a photo or a video? Is it in the metadata?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use pickerResult.type which would have video or image

You can refer the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagepicker/#returns-4)

> Returns If the user cancelled the picking, returns { cancelled: true
> }.
> Otherwise, this method returns information about the selected media
> item. When the chosen item is an image, this method returns {
> cancelled: false, type: 'image', uri, width, height, exif, base64 };
> when the item is a video, this method returns { cancelled: false,
> type: 'video', uri, width, height, duration }.

Answer (score 0):

```jsx
import * as ImagePicker from "expo-image-picker";

const openImagePickerAsync = async() => {
  let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
    mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
    allowsEditing: true,
    quality: 1,
  });
  
  let index = 0 // simple use case

  if (result.assets[index].type == "image") {
    console.log('image')
  } else if (result.assets[index].type == "video") {
    console.log('video')
  } else {
    console.log('none')
  }
}
```